# Spring data MongoDB example not working

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I am just trying to get the "Adding custom behaviour to all repositories" example from the [reference doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) working. But for the following class:

```
public class MyRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
  extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements MyRepository<T, ID> {

  public void sharedCustomMethod(ID id) {
    // implementation goes here
  }
}
```

I get the compilation error

> no suitable constructor found for SimpleJpaRepository()
>   constructor org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.SimpleJpaRepository(java.lang.Class,javax.persistence.EntityManager) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   constructor org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.SimpleJpaRepository(org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation,javax.persistence.EntityManager) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Appropriate solution for 'Adding custom behavior to all repositories' using spring-data mongodb is detailed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23027900/2338248).

After following the steps described in the above post, you can have any of your repository interface to extend the custom-shared-repository-interface as below

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String>,
        WootideRepositoryCustom<Customer, String> {
}
```

The implementation provided in WootideRepositoryImpl will be available in CustomerRepository.

It worked out so well for me.

Wish that the spring data mongodb doc is updated as it is the first place of reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not salty but implementing this is unfortunately not clear at all.

Look at the image for a complete example, github:
https://github.com/mpereira-dev/spring-data-mongo-shared-repo-example

Key points:

1. You must use **@NoRepositoryBean** on the base interface so spring does not create a bean for it.
2. The name of the base interface doesn't matter like it does for adding custom methods to a single repo.
3. The name of the implementing class also doesn't matter
4. Adding **@Repository** to the implementing class will yield the following error :

> Parameter 0 of constructor in
>   com.example.demo.repository.ImplementationRepoNameDoesntMatterEitherUnlikeAddingCustomMethodsToSingleRepo
>   required a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation'
>   that could not be found.

4. You must use:

> @EnableMongoRepositories(
>   repositoryBaseClass = ImplementationRepoNameDoesntMatterEitherUnlikeAddingCustomMethodsToSingleRepo.class)

to tell spring about your base class if you don't you will get this error (spring tries to parse the method into a query):

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property someMethod found for type Person!

5. Make sure your package structure follows the spring conventions so all your components can be discovered by spring, other wise have fun configuring: @ComponentScan, @EntityScan and @EnableMongoRepositories.

[image: A picture says a thousand words]

7.6.2. Adding custom behavior to all repositories

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories

Answer (score -1):

First, this is a simple compile error as the superclass has a constructor you have to either copy or provide an own one. Second, you seem to be mixing up the JPA and MongoDB modules of it. You would rather want to extend `SimpleMongoRepository`.

Comment: Just follow the reference documentation and exchange the Spring Data JPA related types with their equivalents of Spring Data MongoDB.

Comment: I've followed the reference documentation and don't see how to implement a no-arg constructor.

Comment: Love the work Oli, finally go this working for a simple case, but we really need a complete example for Mongo. Best

Answer (score -1):

What @Oliver was saying is that you copy/pasted code incorrectly. The [`Spring-Data-MongoDB Docs`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories) copy/pasted that bit of code from the [`Spring-Data-JPA Docs`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories) and forgot to change it. If you really look at the code you have, the changes are simple.

```
public interface MyMongoRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T, ID> {

    void sharedCustomMethod(ID id);
}


public class MyImplMongoRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleMongoRepository<T, ID> implements MyMongoRepository<T, ID> {

    public void sharedCustomMethod(ID id) {
        // implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Does that make it clear? It was just a typo in the docs.