# Spring Data Mongo Repository:: Common shared method across all Repo issue

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

**Use Case**

I am trying to use *Adding custom behaviour to all repositories* functionality of Spring Data MongoDB.

The documentation unhelpfully describes how to connect using JPA. Anyways got the config setup with Mongo equivalent.

I want to add a findByCategoryName(String categoryName) method to all entities as all my entities will have a Category . Category is a DBRef object so have to use custom query.

Below is relevant part of the config

```
<!-- Activate Spring Data MongoDB repository support -->
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.domain.*.repo" repository-impl-postfix="CustomImpl" 
    factory-class="com.domain.commonrepo.CommonMongoRepoFactoryBean"/>

<bean id="mappingContext" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext" />

<mongo:mapping-converter mapping-context-ref="mappingContext">
    <mongo:custom-converters base-package="com.domain.mongo.converter" />
</mongo:mapping-converter>

<bean id="entityInformationCreator" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.DefaultEntityInformationCreator">
    <constructor-arg name="mappingContext" ref="mappingContext" />
</bean>
```

.
.

**The FactoryBean**

```
    @NoRepositoryBean
    public class CommonMongoRepoFactoryBean<T extends MongoRepository<?,?>, ID extends        
    Serializable> extends MongoRepositoryFactoryBean{

@Autowired
private static MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

protected MongoRepositoryFactory getRepositoryFactory(Class<T> clazz) {
    return new CommonMongoRepoFactory(clazz);
}

private static class CommonMongoRepoFactory extends MongoRepositoryFactory {
    private Class clazz;

    public CommonMongoRepoFactory(Class clazz) {
        super(mongoTemplate);
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public CommonMongoRepoImpl getTargetRepository() {
        return new CommonMongoRepoImpl(clazz);
    }

    public Class<?> getRepositoryClass() {
        return CommonMongoRepoImpl.class;
    }
}
```

I know it's a bit of a hack but with no documentation it is a pain. If anyone knows better PLEASE give me a github link :-)

**Common Repo interface**

```
    @NoRepositoryBean
    public interface CommonMongoRepo<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T,ID> {

public List<T> findByCategoryName(String categoryName);
```

**Implementation**

```
    @NoRepositoryBean
    public class CommonMongoRepoImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleMongoRepository<T,    
    ID> implements CommonMongoRepo<T, ID> {

private Class<T> type;

@Autowired
private static MongoTemplate mongoOperations;

@Autowired
private static EntityInformationCreator entityInformationCreator;

@Autowired
private CategoryRepo categoryRepo;

public CommonMongoRepoImpl(Class<T> type) { 
    super((MongoEntityInformation<T, ID>) entityInformationCreator.getEntityInformation(type), mongoOperations);
}

@Override
public List<T> findByCategoryName(String categoryName) {

    Category category = categoryRepo.findByName(categoryName);

    return mongoOperations.find(query(where("categories.$id").is(category.getId())), type);
}
```

**PROBLEM**

Now when I am trying to use the common method I get an exception

No Property category found in "Entity".  Which is I guess when mongo repo is trying to auto implement the method. This is inspite of me declaring the bean as @NoRepositoryBean

PLEASE HELP!!! Dont want to add the same custom method to all the entities

Comment: The reference documentation uses JPA *as example* as we don't want rewrite the common repository documentation for each store. So you should be fine if you exchange all Spring Data JPA related types with the according Spring Data MongoDB ones (`JpaRepository` -> `MongoRepository` etc.). Ranting about non-existent documentation won't help really (esp. if it does exist). You're always free to submit a pull request for doc improvements if you really care. Would you mind posting the concrete repository interface declaration as well as the repository base class implementation?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Have updated the problem with code.I was reading the Spring-Data-Mongo docs hence expected a Mongo example to be there. And this is not just me, other people are also finding this particular example very difficult to implement >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842481/spring-data-mongodb-example-not-working

Answer (score 9):

Here is the best solution!

Step One:

Add a custom method to interface!

增加一个自定义的方法

**#custom interface**

```
/**
 * Basic Repository for common custom methods
 * @author liangping
 */

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface WootideRepositoryCustom <T, ID extends Serializable>
      extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>, MongoRepository<T, ID> {

      public Page<T> search(Query query, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**Implementation**

Step Two:

Add implement for your custom method!

实现你的自定义方法

```
/**
 * implement for wootide basic repository
 * @author liangping
 */

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository;

public class WootideRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends
        SimpleMongoRepository<T, ID> implements WootideRepositoryCustom<T, ID> {

    public WootideRepositoryImpl(MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> metadata,
            MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        super(metadata, mongoOperations);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<T> search(Query query, Pageable pageable) {
        long total = this.getMongoOperations().count(query, this.getEntityInformation().getJavaType() );
        return new PageImpl<T>(this.getMongoOperations().find(query.with(pageable), this.getEntityInformation().getJavaType()), pageable, total);
    }

}
```

Create a new factory for custom repository

```
/**
 * Repository Factory for all Subrepository
 * @author liangping
 */

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoPersistentEntity;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MappingMongoEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport;
import org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation;
import org.springframework.data.util.TypeInformation;

public class WootideRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends MongoRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
        extends MongoRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport getFactoryInstance(
            MongoOperations operations) {
        return new WootideMongoRepositoryFactory<T,I>( operations );
    }

    private static class WootideMongoRepositoryFactory<T, ID extends Serializable>
            extends MongoRepositoryFactory {

        private MongoOperations mongo;
        public WootideMongoRepositoryFactory(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
            super(mongoOperations);
            this.mongo = mongoOperations;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

            TypeInformation<T> information =  ClassTypeInformation.from((Class<T>)metadata.getDomainType());
            MongoPersistentEntity<T> pe = new BasicMongoPersistentEntity<T>(information);
            MongoEntityInformation<T,ID> mongometa = new MappingMongoEntityInformation<T, ID>(pe);

            return new WootideRepositoryImpl<T, ID>( mongometa,  mongo);
        }

        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return WootideRepositoryCustom.class;
        }
    }
}
```

Make it works

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.***.mongodb" 
factory-class="com.***.mongodb.custom.WootideRepositoryFactoryBean"/>
```

Good Luck! 祝你好运！

Comment: `MongoRepository` already extends `PagingAndSortingRepository`

Comment: How can one specify the factory class using annotations ? Cheers

Comment: What if one only wants a sub-set of the available repositories to have these shared methods? Wouldn't that rule out using base-package ?

Answer (score -1):

Somewhat delayed but [here](https://github.com/rameshpa/spring-mongodb) is sample code that does this for a Spring web app project. The salient points are:

1. Interface used in Controller
2. Implementation done in a separate class that inherits from a base
3. The base implementation provides common methods that any other Controller can use with just a quick inheritance