# How to configure SimpleMongoRepository correctly?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I’m recently working with MongoDB and there is such a problem. I need to configure SimpleMongoRepository, I found this topic as an example (used the last post as an example) [Spring Data Mongo Repository:: Common shared method across all Repo issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260807/spring-data-mongo-repository-common-shared-method-across-all-repo-issue)

Config:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MultipleMongoProperties.class)
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "productcatalog.repository")
public class MultipleMongoConfig {

    private final MultipleMongoProperties mongoProperties;

    @Bean(name = "mongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(primaryFactory(this.mongoProperties.getPrimary()));
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate primaryMongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(primaryFactory(this.mongoProperties.getPrimary()));
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate secondaryMongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(secondaryFactory(this.mongoProperties.getSecondary()));
    }

    @Bean("primary")
    public SimpleMongoRepository<ProductModel, String> getPrimaryProductRepository() {
        TypeInformation<ProductModel> typeInformation = ClassTypeInformation.from(ProductModel.class);
        MongoPersistentEntity<ProductModel> mongoPersistentEntity = new BasicMongoPersistentEntity<>(typeInformation);
        return new SimpleMongoRepository<>(entityInformationFor(mongoPersistentEntity, String.class), primaryMongoTemplate());
    }

    @Bean("secondary")
    public SimpleMongoRepository<ProductModel, String> getSecondaryProductRepository() {
        TypeInformation<ProductModel> typeInformation = ClassTypeInformation.from(ProductModel.class);
        MongoPersistentEntity<ProductModel> mongoPersistentEntity = new BasicMongoPersistentEntity<>(typeInformation);
        return new SimpleMongoRepository<>(entityInformationFor(mongoPersistentEntity, String.class), secondaryMongoTemplate());
    }

    @Bean("productRepository")
    public MongoRepository<ProductModel, String> getRepository() {
        return new MongoRepositoryImpl<>(getPrimaryProductRepository(), getSecondaryProductRepository());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MongoDbFactory primaryFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) {
        return getMongoDbFactory(mongo);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory secondaryFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) {
        return getMongoDbFactory(mongo);
    }

    public <T, ID extends Serializable> MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformationFor(MongoPersistentEntity<T> entity,
                                                                                           Class<ID> idType) {
        return new MappingMongoEntityInformation<>(entity, idType);
    }

    private SimpleMongoDbFactory getMongoDbFactory(MongoProperties mongo) {
        MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential(mongo.getUsername(), mongo.getAuthenticationDatabase(), mongo.getPassword());
        List<MongoCredential> mongoCredentialList = Collections.singletonList(mongoCredential);
        ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress(mongo.getHost(), mongo.getPort());
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddress, mongoCredentialList);
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient,
                mongo.getDatabase());
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "products")
public class ProductModel {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(value = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

But I have a problem that in my SimpleMongoRepository configuration, here in this line

```
MongoPersistentEntity<ProductModel> mongoPersistentEntity = new BasicMongoPersistentEntity<>(typeInformation);
```

idProperty is configured as null and then in subsequent methods where this is used I get NPE. How to solve this problem?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MappingMongoEntityInformation.getIdAttribute(MappingMongoEntityInformation.java:101) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:211) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at productcatalog.repository.MongoRepositoryImpl.findAll(MongoRepositoryImpl.java:97) ~[classes/:na]
at productcatalog.service.impl.ProductServiceImpl.getProductsByIds(ProductServiceImpl.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
at productcatalog.controller.ProductCatalogController.getProductsByIds(ProductCatalogController.java:90) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

I got Repository:

```
public class MongoRepositoryImpl<T, K extends Serializable> implements MongoRepository<T, K> {

    private SimpleMongoRepository<T, K> primaryRepository;

    private SimpleMongoRepository<T, K> secondaryRepository;

    private SimpleMongoRepository<T, K> actualSource;

    private ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    private Lock writeLock = lock.writeLock();
    private Lock readLock = lock.readLock();

    private static final Integer DEFAULT_SIZE = 10;

    public MongoRepositoryImpl(SimpleMongoRepository<T, K> primaryRepository, SimpleMongoRepository<T, K> secondaryRepository) {
        this.primaryRepository = primaryRepository;
        this.secondaryRepository = secondaryRepository;
        actualSource = primaryRepository;
    }

 @Override
    public T findOne(K id) {
        T findResult;
        try {
            readLock.lock();
            findResult = actualSource.findOne(id);
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
        return findResult;
    }


    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        List<T> result;
        try {
            readLock.lock();
            result = actualSource.findAll();
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<T> findAll(Iterable<K> ids) {
        Iterable<T> result;
        try {
            readLock.lock();
            result = actualSource.findAll(ids);
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

All methods work except findAll (Iterable  ids), when I use this method, I got NPE because idProperty = null; How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add full stack trace to identify the problem..

Comment: Added stack trace

Comment: found the solution? seems like working with SimpleMongoRepository is not trivial at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a specialized instance of `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory`.

Set up the factory in your configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MultipleMongoProperties.class)
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "productcatalog.repository", repositoryFactoryBeanClass = MultipleMongoRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class MultipleMongoConfig {
    /* ...code... */
}
```

Then, in your `MultipleMongoRepositoryFactoryBean`:

```
public class MultipleMongoRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends MongoRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable> extends MongoRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    protected RepositoryFactorySupport getFactoryInstance(MongoOperations operations) {
         return new MultipleMongoRepositoryFactory<T, I>(operations);
    }
}
```

Then you create your own set of repositories inside your `MongoRepositoryFactory` according to the metadata.

```
public class MultipleMongoRepositoryFactory<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepositoryFactory {

    private final MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    public MultipleMongoRepositoryFactory(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        super(mongoOperations);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
        /* Add personalyzed stuff here */
        return super.getTargetRepository(metadata);
    }

}
```

Notice that `MongoRepositoryFactory::getEntityInformation(EntityMetadata)` has a method that returns the `MongoEntityInformation`, which is actually throwing the exception from your configuration. Therefore, in case you REALLY need to manually configure your repository you can try injecting `MongoRepositoryFactory`.

Notice that this is only necessary if you need to implement specific things over your repositories implementations. If you only use the default interfaces that Spring Data provide nothing like this will be necessary.

**EDIT:** You can check in Spring Data's docs for more information. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.6.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations. This was retrieved from version 1.6.4, which is the one I experienced the same problem as yourself. For the current release, please refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I got the very same challenge, and unfortunately could not find a decent example for how to do this.

As you can see from stack trace, `SimpleMongoRepository` holds internally `MongoEntityInformation`, and in 3 cases it explicitly searches for the Id attribute: both `findAllById()`, `existsById()` and `deleteById()` call eventually to `entityInformation.getIdAttribute()`. So you must ensure it is familiar with your entity and its Id attribute.

This is how you do this:

```
@Bean("primary")
public SimpleMongoRepository<ProductModel, String> getPrimaryProductRepository() {

    TypeInformation<ProductModel> typeInformation = ClassTypeInformation.from(ProductModel.class);
    BasicMongoPersistentEntity<ProductModel> mongoPersistentEntity = new BasicMongoPersistentEntity<ProductModel>(typeInformation);
    //add Id-property, o/w SimpleMongoRepository asks (e.g. delete())  getIdQuery(id) and we fail on `entityInformation.getIdAttribute()`
    Class<ProductModel>  aClass = ProductModel.class;
    Field field = null;
    try
    {
        field = aClass.getDeclaredField("id");
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Property property = Property.of(ClassTypeInformation.from(ProductModel.class), field);
    MongoPersistentProperty idProperty = new BasicMongoPersistentProperty(property , mongoPersistentEntity, SimpleTypeHolder.DEFAULT, null);
    mongoPersistentEntity.addPersistentProperty(idProperty);
    MongoEntityInformation<ProductModel, String> mongoEntityInformation = new MappingMongoEntityInformation<ProductModel, String>(mongoPersistentEntity); 

    return new SimpleMongoRepository<>(mongoEntityInformation, primaryMongoTemplate());
}
```

...and same for 'secondary'.

Hope that helps.